# Script de terminal de numeros en php

Tags: php, mysql, php-cli

He tratado de crear un script que me ayude a llevar código de cada persona y la variante es que no es un auto incremento del mismo es decir, Eje: El terminal de numero se vasa de la siguiente forma 0 0 0 lo cual el incremento se vera en tercer numero 0 0 1 llegado a cien este tercer numero es reiniciado 0 0 1... 0 0 100 y volverá a cero y el segundo numero sera incrementado 0 1 0 así sucesivamente.
Como he dicho anteriormente he tratado de desarrollar algo parecido pero he terminado en fracaso

Comment: Deberías añadir qué has intentado y qué errores recibiste.

Comment: @Josbert Pese a dar una respuesta, voto para cerrar. Por lo menos, un lenguaje: ¿ php, javascript, sql ? Ya llevas tiempo en el sitio, sabes como funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que con algo como esto debería valerte:

```
<?php

$numbers = [0,0,0];

for ($numbers[2]=0; $numbers[2] <= 101; $numbers[2]++)
{ 

    if( $numbers[2] == 101 ) 
    {

        $numbers[2] = 0;

        $numbers[1]++;

        if( $numbers[1] == 101 ) 
        {

            $numbers[1] = 0;

            $numbers[0]++;

            if( $numbers[0] == 100 ) 
            {

                $numbers[2] = 0;

                $numbers[1] = 0;

                break;

            }

        }

    }

    echo $numbers[0] . ' ' . $numbers[1] . ' ' . $numbers[2] . '<br>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que quieres hacer ya lo tienes hecho. Te estás limitando a mostrar distinto dígitos de un número.

```
0 00 00 -> 000000
0 01 00 -> 000100
1 99 05 -> 019905
```

Puedes usar un entero e incrementarlo tanquilamente.

Cuando necesites acceder a sus partes concretas, es donde has de hacer una pequeña operación:

```
$numero = 110;
$cadena = '00000' . (string)$numero;
$numeros = [
  0 => substr( $cadena, -6, 2 ),
  1 => substr( $cadena, -4, 2 ),
  2 => substr( $cadena, -2, 2 ),
];

echo "{$numeros[0]}, {$numeros[1]}, {$numeros[2]}\n";
```